# How add SetTimeout to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i want add "settimeout" or "await sleep" for this code.

```
    async function handleRequest(request) {
  if (request.method !== 'GET') return MethodNotAllowed(request)
  return new Response(html, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8",
      }
  })
}
```

I would like the html content to be shown for a certain period of time.

User - rewrite site to html 5 secound - back to site.

Comment: That sounds like server-side JavaScript. It's not going to be able to affect the client's refresh/timeout behavior.

Comment: Hello,

This is the server side, I would like to display a static page and then go back to the normal page.

I can't bite it well.

Answer (score 0):

That control should be done in the HTML that is being sent to the client-side.

In case you don't have permission to do it directly in the HTML, you can concatenate a script to your response.

```js
const htmlWithTimeout = `${html}<script>setTimeout(() => "REDIRECT IN 5 SEC", 5000)</script>`;
```

Is this a good solution? No it is not.

Do we have another option for HTTP response? Not out-of-the-box.

A less hammered solution:

On your client-side have a generic way to redirect with timeout and use headers or cookies to communicate that between FE and BE.